# Como obtener el utlimo registro si uso group by

Tags: mysql

necesito listar a todos los usuarios que hallan creado una votación, un usuario puede crear muchas votaciones y ese usuario pertenece a una empresa.

Los estoy agrupando porque necesito la ultima votación por usuario, pero necesito que se ordenen las votaciones en curso primero (4) y luego las votaciones finalizadas (5)

```
select u.nombre, v.contexto, v.fecha
from users u
inner join empresas e on e.id = u.empresa_id
inner join votacion v on u.id = v.user_id 
where v.fecha <= now() and ( v.estado = "4" or v.estado = "5" )
group by u.id 
order by v.estado asc, v.fecha desc, v.id desc
```

El problema que tengo es en la columna contexto y fecha, porque me trae el resultado del primer registro que encuentra y yo necesito el ultimo, como puedo ordenar los registros antes de agruparlos?

**@UPDATE**

La siguiente query cumple mi objetivo

```
select count(v.user_id) as total, u.nombre, v.contexto, v.fecha, v.estado
from users u
inner join empresas e on e.id = u.empresa_id
inner join 
        ( select fecha, 
                 user_id, 
                 contexto, 
                 estado 
          from votacion 
          where fecha <= now() AND (estado = "4" or estado = "5")
          order by estado, fecha desc, id desc 
         ) v
on u.id = v.user_id
group by u.id
order by v.estado
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sería la forma correcto de hacerlo? o esto es un sobrecarga para la base de datos?

Comment: entonces primero ordena por usuario,luego por fecha

Comment: entonces primero ordena por usuario,luego por fecha

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que preguntas y tu consulta no cumple un estándar real de agrupación. ¿La columna `nombre` es necesaria en los resultados?  Si lo es, debes incluirla en una función de agrupación, así sea `GROUP_CONCAT` u otra. Puedes incluir `v.contexto` y `v.fecha` en el `GROUP BY` usando en ellas funciones de agrupación también, por ejemplo: `MIN(v.contexto), MIN(v.fecha)`, así cumples con el estándar SQL y ya no tienes que incluir esas columnas en el `ORDER BY` porque las función `MIN` te traerá el valor más pequeño.

Comment: en mi caso max(v.fecha) me sirve, pero v.contexto es un campo tipo text

Answer (score 1):

Estoy seguro de que alguien pueda darte una mejor solución que ésta, pero funciona:
Lo que yo haría es primero crear una vista que me de todos los id máximos de las votaciones de cada usuario, ej.:

```
CREATE VIEW `vw_votacionmaxima` AS
    SELECT 
        `users`.`id` AS `user_id`,
        MAX(`votacion`.`id`) AS `votacionmax_id`
    FROM
        (`votacion`
        JOIN `users` ON ((`votacion`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`)))
    GROUP BY `votacion`.`user_id`;
```

Con ésta vista (que solo se crea una vez en tu base de datos) tu select te da el resultado que buscas:

```
SELECT
    users.nombre,
    votacion.contexto,
    votacion.fecha 
FROM
    vw_votacionmaxima
    INNER JOIN users ON vw_votacionmaxima.user_id = users.id
    INNER JOIN votacion ON vw_votacionmaxima.votacionmax_id = votacion.id 
WHERE
    votacion.fecha <= now( ) 
    AND ( votacion.estado = "4" OR votacion.estado = "5" ) 
ORDER BY
    vw_votacionmaxima.votacionmax_id DESC,
    votacion.fecha DESC
```

Espero que pruebes y te funcione!.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar por qué sugieres crear una vista para resolver esto?

Comment: Porque no se como llegar al resultado buscado en una sola consulta es por lo que comencé la repuesta diciendo **"Estoy seguro de que alguien pueda darte una mejor solución que ésta"**

Comment: El hecho es que es relativamente fácil llegar al resultado buscado, no creo que haga falta una vista para eso. Si por cada cosa que no sepas vas a crear una vista en vez de aprender como se hace, te vas a encontrar con cientos o miles de vistas en el manejador de base de datos.

Comment: Por suerte tenemos una plataforma como ésta donde hay programadores dispuestos a optimizar el código propuesto aquí como solución, espero que alguien mejore mi repuesta para ir **aprendiendo cada día mas**; que es claro de lo que se trata todo ésto.